# Unhandled promise rejection with Promise.allSettled and try/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, try-catch

My idea is as follows:
I want to send multiple requests simultaneously without having to wait until priors execution.

So my pseudo code looks as follows:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function failingRequest(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('Request failed');
    });
}

function successRequest(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('Request success');
    });
}

async function main() {
    try {
        let executions = [];
        executions.push(failingRequest());
        await sleep(4000);
        executions.push(successRequest());
        let result = await Promise.allSettled(executions);
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Outer error occured.');
        console.log(err.message);
    }

    console.log('done');
}
main();
```

Running this code here works as intended in the browser but gives me following output running with node:

```
node:761) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Request failed
api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:761) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exi not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[
  { status: 'rejected', reason: 'Request failed' },
  { status: 'fulfilled', value: 'Request success' }
]
done
(node:761) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Note that I only inserted `sleep` so I could test if the `catch` block will be executed in case the first request fails **WHICH WOULD NOT BE THE DESIRED BEHAVIOR**. I want to initiate those requests all at the same time and I do not care if one fails. I want to check later with `let result = await Promise.allSettled(executions);` which requests worked and which failed. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Would you prefer to use async await?

Comment: Please read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @DipakC OP already does use async/await?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question - the problem is that you're not actually simulating async requests. In fact your two request-methods are simply creating promises which are resolved/rejected synchronously/immediately. You would need to put `await` before `failingRequest()` in order for the rejected promise to be caught in the surrounding `try/catch` but this is probably not what you want.

Instead you should not "start" the promises immediately, it should rather be something like:

```
try {
        let executions = [];
        executions.push(failingRequest);
        await sleep(4000);
        executions.push(successRequest);
        let result = await Promise.allSettled(executions.map(promiseFn => promiseFn()));
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Outer error occured.');
        console.log(err.message);
    }
```

This will log

```
[
  { status: 'rejected', reason: 'Request failed' },
  { status: 'fulfilled', value: 'Request success' }
]
done
```

as expected.

Comment: Interesting answer aswell. I did not think of that and it seems to work... But going back to my original test: Would this prevent executing the `catch` block if lets say a request times out after 10 seconds? I need to be sure all `executions` will be executed no matter if they resolve or reject individually.

Comment: Yes, if you do it this way, it is guaranteed that all executions will be executed. You can even simulate it by adding a `setTimeout` in your request-functions. I've created a fiddle for you with a modified version of your code that maybe helps you understand what's going on: https://jsfiddle.net/1rfpksvu/

Comment: This is awesome! I was wondering how I would apply arguments to those functions but `.bind()` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get why you would do this. You could equally just move the `await sleep(4000);` line before the creation of the `executions` array.

Comment: The point I tried to make is that the promises were executed synchronously/immediately with OP's original code and that the immediately rejected promise was not caught anymore due to the `await sleep(..)`. Of course, in my example, the `await sleep` does not make a lot of sense, but I decided to keep it in order for the OP to understand.

Comment: In my actual code I'm executing request Block1 (execution1) and then Block2 (execution2). After that I wait with Promise.allSettled() for Block2 and after that the same way for Block1. As seen here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbk2a59h/6/) . This does not work as intended... Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Working now as intended with: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbk2a59h/10/)

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why this is happening?

You create the `failingRequest()` and then wait 4 seconds before handling it.

> I only inserted sleep so I could test

… and thereby you caused the unhandled rejection. Remove the `await sleep(4000);` and it'll work as expected!

Comment: If I add those functions 1 Million times like so ```let executions = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            executions.push(failingRequest());
            executions.push(successRequest());
        }```

The first rejection does not seem to be handled immediately either and still there will not by any `Unhandled promise rejection`...

Comment: Yes it is handled immediately (=synchronously) by the `Promise.allSettled(executions)` call. But then it waits 4 seconds *afterwards* for the settling of these promises, before logging the result of all executions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code first calls `failingRequest`, which creates a promise that is rejected immediately. JavaScript pushes this rejected promise to the [microtask queue to be processed right after the `main` function has completed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide).

[JavaScript continues the execution of `main`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#run-to-completion) and when it runs `await sleep(4000)`, it returns control to the event loop (so JavaScript can resume it 4 seconds later). The event loop pulls a task from the microtask queue, which is the `failingRequest` promise; JavaScript notices it doesn't have a `.catch()` or a `Promise.allSettled()` handler and throws the `UnhandledPromiseRejection` error.

If you don't return control to the event loop between the time the promises are created and added to `Promise.allSettled`, `Promise.allSettled` runs before the `failingRequest` message is processed from the microtask queue, resulting in `Promise.allSettled` handling the promise rejection by marking it as rejected.

These links provide additional details:

1. [Microtasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide)
2. [Run-to-completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#run-to-completion) (*)
3. [Zero delays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop#zero_delays)
4. [Using Promises - Guarantees](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#guarantees)

(*) To be more precise, the event loop doesn't wait for the `main` function
to finish, but instead waits for the current synchronous code to finish.
In this case, it's the code up to the `await sleep(4000);` line. After
this line, the `main` function is paused, and the event loop can handle
other tasks, including the rejected `failingRequest` promise.